# Load image and css in Golang

Tags: html, css, image, go, template-engine

I setup a route in `server.js` in package `main` in root directory of project

`http.HandleFunc("/",route.IndexHandler)`

The `IndexHandler` is implemented in package `route` like this:

```
func IndexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data:=struct{
        Name string
    }{
        "My name",
    }
    util.RenderTemplate(w, "index", data)
}
```

The `RenderTemplate` function is implemented in package `util` like this:

```
func RenderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, data interface{}) {
    cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
    t, err := template.ParseFiles(filepath.Join(cwd, "./view/" + tmpl + ".html"))
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    err = t.Execute(w, data)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

Directory structure in project like this:

```
/
/public/css
/public/images
/public/js
/route
/view
```

`index.html` view is located in folder `view`, router is in folder `route`

In `index.html` I include resources like these:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/style.css">`

`<img src="../public/images/img_landing_page_mac.png">`

When request the appropriate path, `index.html` is still rendered, but images and stylesheet are not loaded. How can I do to include them in Golang html template engine?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to explicitly ask your server to serve static files.

See [http.FileServer](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer)

In your case register another handler.

```
http.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Aruna said, register a static file server handle

```
http.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))))
```

And to use the files in your HTML, simply

```
<img src="/public/images/img_landing_page_mac.png">
```